# Problem with cloudpanel on Installing vsftpd on ubuntu server

Tags: vsftpd

I am trying to install vsftpd on my ubuntu 22.04 server. After running apt install vsftpd command and confirmation of the installation I am getting the following error:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cloudpanel proftpd-basic proftpd-core proftpd-mod-crypto proftpd-mod-wrap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vsftpd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/123 kB of archives.
After this operation, 301 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 135669 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cloudpanel (2.3.2-1+clp-jammy) ...
This account is currently not available.
dpkg: error processing package cloudpanel (--remove):
 installed cloudpanel package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cloudpanel
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even when I try to unistall the Cloudpanel, I am getting exactly the same problem. I am running VPS server where the cloudpanel was probably pre-installed.

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud panel already comes with an FTP server called ProFTPd. No need to install another FTP server.